# What does This quote from Hello Android book mean?

Tags: android

"In Android, an application can be “alive” even if its process has been
killed. Put another way, the activity life cycle is not tied to the process
life cycle. Processes are just disposable containers for activities. This is
probably different from every other system you’re familiar with, so let’s
take a closer look before moving on." 
I dont understand what they mean by alive,as far as I know,if I am not wrong,all activities in an application is driven by one linux process.So how can an application is "alive" even if the process is killed?

Answer (score 0):

"If I am not wrong,all activities in an application is driven by one linux process,all activities in an application is driven by one linux process"

Yes and no. You can perfectly have [orphan processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_process) that are alive "children" processes whose "parent" processes are dead. Here it's this kind of things that you have so that if a process with alive foreground activity dies it will be restarted.